# Flow to iterate through all Plans

Tags: power-automate

I am using flow to send reminders to members and managers for overdue tasks (adapting from this template https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/a00e201320624ed493240974cbebf2ae/send-reminder-email-for-incomplete-planner-tasks-in-a-plan/).

The flow works OK when I select a specific Plan ID, however I need to expand on this to loop through all plans (so it will pickup on future added plans).

How can I obtain a list of all plans, and pass them in a apply to each block please?

[image: flow]

Comment: You can check the action "Get plans from group". The idea is to get the plans that way, and then, inside the loop, use the logic you already have.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I came across and implemented is to manually create a JSON config file with an array of user names, plan IDs and whatever you need.
Then upload it to OneDrive and in flows that need that information pull it from OneDrive. Then parse JSON file and iterate over the users and plans as you need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).